# how to pass the current directory as argument in platypus and default python version for Platypus

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, platypus

I finally managed to package python/PyQt4 based tool using Platypus, however since my executable python script can take the directory from which the application is run as argument

I don't know how to pass the current directory as argument through platypus, I tried ${PWD} but this too doesn't work.

I also tried using Script Type to Env > that has the same issue !!!

[image]

Secondly, this is confusing, the default python version i had set on my OSx is Python 2.7.1

but the platypus Script type > Python gives /usr/bin/python which turns out to be python 2.6

So I manually changed the python script type to 
Other > /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

this makes launching application by double clicking PythonTool.app

Also, if i set /usr/bin/env python gives me python version 2.7.4 but launching by double clicking doesn't work , but if we go inside MacOS folder add click on executable binary script, then it work..

And if I give the path of PythonFramework 2.7 does this mean if I give the osx application package  to someone he would need to have the above path of Python 2.7 ?